# Can anyone explain, in Go programming language are values stored in the Stack?

Tags: go

I got the Example struct and where my is object allocated?

```
type Example struct {
   field_a int
}

var ex Example = Example{10} // Stack's object or Heap ?
var ex Example = new(Example{10}) // Stack's object or Heap ?
```

Comment: Go as a language has neither heap nor stack, only some implementations of Go distinguish memory into heap and stack. Where smth is stored depends on the exact version of the compiler, target system and changes regularly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike C or C++, you don't know, golang abstracts the memory allocation.
Moreover, you cannot choose where the memory is allocated.